# Failing to send checkbox value to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to store a Boolean value in my database based off a checkbox(Watched) in a form. If the checkbox isn't checked on form submit, it should send a 0; Otherwise a 1.

However, it sends a value of 0 no matter if it's checked or not. The Title Field and Genre field send perfectly, however the Watched conditional is not working correctly. I'm stumped and having a hard time wrapping my head around this, any thoughts?

```
<?php 

    require 'config/config.php';
    require 'config/db.php';

    // Check for Submit
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Get Form Data
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
        $genre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['genre']);
        if (isset($_POST['watched']) && ($_POST['watched'] == "value")) {
            $watched = 1;
        } else {
            $watched = 0;
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO movies(name, genre, watched) VALUES('$title', '$genre', '$watched')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'');
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }

?>

                <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control" name="title">
                        <label for="form1" class="">Title</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="md-form">
                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control" name="genre">
                        <label for="form1" class="">Genre</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="watched">
                        <label for="checkbox1">Have you watched it already?</label>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

                </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked what value `$_POST['watched']` has?

Comment: when it is not checked it is not sent. You are mistaking it with radio buttons probably

Comment: When checked it is string "on", otherwise it is NULL @Marvin

Comment: I'm aware it is not sent when not checked, I'm trying to send a value for watched based off it has a value or not @BabakBandpey

Comment: @Temple what value do you expect from your checkbox when it is checked? you have this `if (isset($_POST['watched']) && ($_POST['watched'] == "value"))`, are you looking for the value "value"? it could be enough if it is just set. isn't it?

Comment: Yup! That was it. Thank you, if you leave a answer I'd be happy to mark you as correct.

Comment: `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks

Comment: What would you recommend sir? @RaymondNijland

Comment: just use action="" should also post the form to the same page. or use htmlspecialchars()

Comment: Ah, yes forgot to insert htmlspecialchars(). Thanks, @RaymondNijland

Comment: @Temple happy that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You never set an actual value for the checkbox in your form HTML, so the value of the checkbox will never exist which means your if statement will always return false.

Simply change this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="watched">
```

to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="watched" value="value">
```